# BigQuery Error: Cannot partition on repeated field hits.product.sku

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
  a.fv fv,
  a.v v,
  a.sku asku
  b.sku bsku from(
  SELECT
    fv,
    v,
    sku from( FLATTEN((
        SELECT
          fullvisitorid fv,
          visitid v,
          hits.product.productsku sku,
          hits.product.isclick click
        FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([dataset_id], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), -5, 'day'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), -0, 'day'))),
          (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([dataset_id_intraday_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), -2, 'day'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), 0, 'day')))), hits.product))
  WHERE
    1 = 1
    AND click IS NOT NULL
  GROUP EACH BY
    fv,
    v,
    sku ) a
LEFT JOIN EACH (
  SELECT
    fv,
    v,
    sku from( FLATTEN((
        SELECT
          fullvisitorid fv,
          visitid v,
          hits.product.productsku sku,
          hits.ecommerceaction.action_type act
        FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([dataset_id], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), -5, 'day'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), -0, 'day'))),
          (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([dataset_id._intraday_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), -2, 'day'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), 0, 'day')))), hits.product))
  WHERE
    1 = 1
    AND act = '6' ) b
ON
  a.fv = b.fv
  AND a.v = b.v
  AND a.sku = b.sku
```

This query is just an example of the problem we are having here. If we try to run it, we get the error:

```
Error: Cannot partition on repeated field hits.product.sku
```

But we couldn't figure out what's wrong.

There are basically two groups: `a` is the group where we bring skus and if they had any clicks.
Group `b` we just observe wether the given sku was purchased or not.

We then `left join` to match `fullvisitors`, their `session id` and each `sku`.

But even when we tried applying the `FLATTEN` function we still have the same error message.

We know we are doing something wrong but couldn't find so far what it is.

Is there some mistake in the query?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Note that you're less likely to hit these types of issues when using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) in BigQuery. For differences between legacy and standard SQL, take a look at the [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql).

Comment: We will start migrating all of all queries to the standard version now. The advantages are also quite good so hopefully we'll solve several problems with that. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Please check most inner SELECTs
I feel it might be a problem with "misspelling" the field name.

I just tried your whole query and it worked for me - when i changed
`hits.product.sku` to `hits.item.productsku`

Comment: Thanks for the help Mikhail. I did try running the `inner selects` and individually they work normally. Only when I combine both in the `group` operation is that I get this error. Also tried changing the field names but to no success. I'll try to fix it using some other type of query